# How to pass std::vector with POD data from C++ to Lua?

Tags: c++, binding, lua, stdvector

I am new to Lua and C++-Lua binding and currently I have weird problem. This works:

- I can pass `std::vector` of custom, complex, type and get the size of it in Lua
- I can access any element of above `std::vector` in Lua and execute a method on it

also:

- I can pass `std::vector` of POD type (like `int`) and get the size of it in Lua (size of `std::vector`)

However I am unable to get given `int` from the vector, entire app crashes when trying to do.

The irony is, all bindings for `std::vector` is made via the same helper function(2 example functions here):

```
template < typename T_ >
void BindVectorOf( luabind::class_< std::vector< T_ > > & vectorClass )
{
    typedef std::vector< T_ > Vector;
    typedef Vector::reference ( Vector::* AtMethod )( Vector::size_type );

    vectorClass
            .def( luabind::constructor< >( ) )
            .def( "Size",     &Vector::size )
            .def( "At",       (AtMethod)&Vector::at )
        );
}
```

So in short above `Size` method works always, but `At` method works only on complex (custom) types, it does not work for `int` for example.

Does Lua have something against POD types? :-) What I am missing?

*Update 1: to be on the safe side, I tried to bind and then force `int32_t` to make int 32-bit, no difference, on first access to `std::vector` element I have crash.*

*Update 2: to make sure some type coercion does not kick in, I removed binding for `std::vector<int>` leaving `float`, and then I passed `std::vector<float>`. Same result as before.*

*Update 3: out of curiosity I tried to access elements using index operator, i.e. `my_vector[x]` in Lua. No crash, but as the result I got `nil` (I have required element, even with +1 shift).*

**Solution:** I solved the problem in this way -- for POD types I don't return a reference to value (as above), but the value itself. But I would love to know why Lua has problem with reference.

Comment: This isn't a MWE. Please include one. Why are you casting `std::vector<T>::at` to an identical signature? Using C-style casts in C++ is very dangerous when `T` can be polymorphic.

Comment: Why mess around with passing a vector when you can just call `vector::data()` to get you the pointer to the buffer?  Once you have this pointer, it can be treated as an array of `T`.  I don't know lua bindings, but if you can get it to understand a `T*`, that's all you need.\

Comment: @Tim, this is part of much bigger program, which I did **not** write, I am supposed to just pass those data and work in Lua. As for casting, I am not the author (so I don't know) and POD types are not polymorphic, but where is the danger? `T` is passed via reference here, or this remark was general one?

Comment: @greenoldman What I'm saying is that a lot of the complexity can be removed if you passed a `T*`, and that `T*` can be gotten by calling `vector::data()`.   A vector stores its data in contiguous memory, no different than an ordinary array.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie, this could technically work but it does not solve the essence of the problem. `std::vector<T>` is a valid type and it can work, I don't want to run away from the problem just because I have problem with POD types.